# Overhead of Services in Android (how many should I create)

Tags: android, performance, service, overhead

Does anybody know how big the overhead for services in Android is.
And if there are any other argument helping me with the following design decision.

I have two SQLite Dbs, one storing actual data (basically read only product inventory), the other storing settings, lists of selected items, etc.

Now I created a service to take care of manageing these databases, for two main reasons:

- I want to be able to "save on close" (settings), which is possible with the onDestroy
- It takes some time to load the data, so a quick close of the app keeps the data in memory

From a design perspective, I could either:

- Create one service handling both DBs
- Create two services, each handling one DB

It feels cleaner to create a seperate service for each DB, e.g. extending a generic base class to take care of shutdown, timers, etc. It also allows me to configure them independent (which is NOT required right now).

On the other hand, I do not want to start going down this road, and then, when I am used to doing stuff like this in "services" discovering that there is a limit of 3 or 5 services.

So how is the Overhead of e.g. 5 running services, vs. one service hosting 5 different features? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of services effectively supported by Android should be nothing to worry about in your situation. Having seen lists of running services in some task managers, I tend to say that up to ~100 "running" services should be no problem on most devices.

However, I'm not sure if what you're trying to do actually *should* be implemented in a service. Can you elaborate why you think you need a service?

> I want to be able to "save on close" (settings), which is possible with the onDestroy

Can't you do this in your normal Activity lifecycle callbacks?

> It takes some time to load the data, so a quick close of the app keeps the data in memory

What do you mean by "quick close"? Are you trying to build some sort of *cache* for the DB data?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Regarding A - no, I dont want to save on each activity-switch. Only on "applicationExit", and there is nothing like this in the ApplicationClass (onTerminate only applies to emulator).

Comment: Regarding B, its a nice side effect of using a service. Even if the App gets killed, the service can hold on to the objects a little bit longer (and terminate itself after e.g. 30 min of non usage) - but dont worry, my main motivation is A - saving at exit, not page switch.

Comment: Ok, in that case, it seems to me that a service is probably the only viable way to reliably be notified of an application's death. (I don't see a.t.m. why Android does not provide a corresponding callback; didn't bother to further investigate, though.) You probably want to *bind* to the service so the service will be implicitly destroyed once the (last) binding client goes away. - I just found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7236782/is-an-android-service-guaranteed-to-call-ondestroy) about *onDestroy()* of a service... Seems like its not too easy to do what you want.

Comment: WTF....Damn and I thought I had it. Why the heck don't they provide a simple "onDestroy" callback. I dont want to save on every page switch! Damn damn damn... Well I can do it now (have the infrastructure in place anyway, but still)... Well, offtopic. Thanks for your answer and the link!

Comment: Welcome. And don't let them upset you too much :)

Answer (score 1):

From the Android dev docs...

> Use services sparingly

http://developer.android.com/training/articles/memory.html#Services

Answer (score 0):

If services are RemoteServices then they are launched in a separate process which add overhead and is memory intensive.

Try using a single service for both the scenarios.