# How to restart service in android?

Tags: android

I have started a service in an activity. When I close the activity, the activity service is also getting stop.

Is there any way to restart it automatically.?

Comment: *" if i force close the activity"*...how are you exactly accomplishing this?

Comment: Yes, u can. Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15758980/android-service-need-to-run-alwaysnever-pause-or-stop/15775964#15775964 you don't have to do the notification part

Comment: depends on when you want to restart it *automatically*.

Comment: yes if service is stopped then automatically restart this service.

Comment: If user force close the app, i think the service *must* not restart unless user launches your app again. http://stackoverflow.com/a/27857906/1939564

Comment: Post some code Krishna

Answer (score 1):

If you want your service to run in background , without stopping it , then start your service as sticky .

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    /* your code goes here */
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Comment: based my own experience, START_STICKY not guarantee the service to restart automatically. my case is when the user click home button on the device. then the user use other apps for example facebook, whatsapp for a minute. then if user open the app, the service already gone eventhough the service already used START_STICKY

Answer (score 0):

this is the worst problem, whatever you do.. you service never be restart until you open your application. but in `API 21` android developer added [Job Schedular](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html) to maintain background services. you can use this to schedule your services regarding time, and internet connectivity and so on.

for more information you can refer this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fd1ORa8PDso).    HAPPY CODING.

Answer (score -1):

```
private void restartService() {
    Intent restartIntent = new Intent(this, ScreenLockService.class);
    PendingIntent restartServicePI = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 1, restartIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    AlarmManager alarmService = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmService.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000, restartServicePI);
}
```