# Disable force stop button in manage application

Tags: java, android, forceclose

I am trying to disable the force stop button in the manage application page in Android settings. Certain applications are able to this even when their service is in running state the force stop button comes in disabled state.
Please can anyone help me with this?

Comment: can you give me an example of an app that does this?  To me this would seem extremely bad, why would you limit the users ability to force an applicaion to close?

Comment: Which applications? AFAIK only a system app could do that.

Comment: You should search for the reason why the forces stop dialog appears in your application instead disabling it!

Comment: An Parental lock application is able to do this....its name is **kaspersky parental control**...pls check it...its service is running and then also the force stop button is disabled

Comment: @eftokay83:It is not that my application is crashing. I am talking about the force stop button which you see in the setting->Manage applicaition->Your application

Comment: Yes i agree , Applications like Kaspersky Parental Control do not allow Force Stop of itself

Answer (score 5):

I am finding since last 1 week and finally I found that how to disable the Force Stop button.

You should apply Device Administrator Policy to your application.
Below url will help you.

http://prashantandroid.blogspot.in/2013/07/disable-force-stop-in-manage.html

Comment: This approach should be only used for apps which want to be Device Admin, also looks like that this is vendor specific implementation & the button is not disabled on few Lenovo tabs

Comment: Is it still working approach. Also will Google allow us to publish such apps on play store?

Answer (score 4):

> I am trying to disable the force stop button in the manage application page in Android settings.

Fortunately, this is not possible for ordinary SDK applications, for obvious security reasons.

> Certain applications are able to this even when their service is in running state the force stop button comes in disabled state

Some system apps can do this, I believe. You are welcome to make your own custom ROM and attempt to prevent your app from being force-stopped.

Comment: Pls check **Kaspersky parental Control** it is not a system application then also it is somehow able to do it

Comment: @untraceable: I will work to prevent Kaspersky from being able to do this in the future. Thank you for pointing out a potential security flaw in Android.

Comment: hey can u help me with how kaspersky is able to do this

Comment: @untraceable: I am certainly not going to help you possibly exploit a security flaw in Android.

Comment: Fortunately, Kaspersky Parental Control behaves like any other app, and can be force-stopped, at least as of Android 4.0 (as I did not bother trying it on any older version).

Comment: The same Kaspersky application does not allow Force STOP on Android 2.2
Please Help , how are they able to access FORCE STOP functionality

Comment: I tried an anti-theft program called "Prey" that I couldn't uninstall.  I think that was in Android 2.x though.

Comment: "Some system apps can do this, I believe." - would you know how they do it? (I have system permissions, root access and I'm compiling the app with hidden/internal APIs)

Comment: @DADi590: No, sorry, I do not know how that is accomplished.