# restarting the service after manually killing it

Tags: android, android-service

i want to start service in android if its being killed manually by a user ,i have read a lot about this and here what i am using in my service

my service is fetching a current user location on a regular interval and its a START_STICKY service. as i have read that `whatsapp` is using `GCM` to turn on the service again if its being manually killed by the user , so i have implemented `GCM` too and enable the service.

but if i manually killed my service then `GCM` also gets stopped ( which is an obvious reason) , so i think its a **MYTH** that `whatsapp` is using `GCM` to restart their own service , there is no magic behind `whtsapp`.

i have tried restarting the service by calling `startService` from `onDestroy` but that doesnt work too.

i have tried to run service as a separate process too by using process attribute but it doesnt effect

so is there still any way to immediately restart the service if its being killed by the user itself

***note: i already know that if service is being killed by the user manually , OS will restart it soon automatically if the service is `START_STICKY`***

Answer (score 0):

Actually whats app service never be stopped any time if any user stop it manually it started in very short time because of AlarmManager. use alarmmanager instead of START_STICKY flag.
Your service automatically started after killed by user. check link :
http://androidsamplecodes4u.blogspot.in/2012/08/start-service-with-alarm-manager-android.html

Comment: if i am killing the service manually how my AlaramManager will gonna know when to restart as it might get killed with the processes attached with the app itself

Comment: have you check above link example? there are pendingintent use. in pending intent you have to set interval after that interval your service call if you set interval to 1 mnt and set alrmmngr.setrepeating(...,pendingintent) then your service call after every 1 mnt...

Answer (score 0):

override this method in your service hope it works

```
@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    Intent restartService = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            this.getClass());
    restartService.setPackage(getPackageName());
    PendingIntent restartServicePI = PendingIntent.getService(
            getApplicationContext(), 1, restartService,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    //Restart the service once it has been killed android


    AlarmManager alarmService = (AlarmManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmService.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() +1000, restartServicePI);

}
```

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10671460/restart-the-service-even-if-app-is-force-stopped-and-keep-running-service-in-bac) refer this

Comment: do you think alarm manager will stay alive to trigger this service?