# Android: receive message without a service running

Tags: android, push-notification

As far as I knew, if you "Force stop" an application, then all the services and processes started from that app are terminated. That's why I didn't try to find a way to keep a message service running after my app was brutally closed, I thought it was impossible.

Then I've found out that if I force close Whatsapp and someone sends me a message, I still get a notification.

How is it possible ?

> OK, my fail, it's definetely not possible as designed by Google. I did
> the test again, force closed whatsapp and didn't get any notification.
>
> So, eventhough pressing a button "Force stop" dosen't offer many ways to fail, I must have done something wrong the first time I tested.

Comment: Presumably, they are using Google Cloud Messaging.

Comment: Since GCM uses an explicit `Intent` to invoke your `BroadcastReceiver`, it should be capable of moving your app out of the stopped state.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll try to find out more with the help of these new info

Answer (score 0):

Although this is a little old, I belive it can help you:
[Restart the service even if app is force-stopped and Keep running service in background even after closing the app   How?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10671460/restart-the-service-even-if-app-is-force-stopped-and-keep-running-service-in-bac)

yakobom

Comment: That thread just confirms what I knew, it's not possible. I also checked with the task manager and there was no whatsapp process running.

Comment: It is very likely that they are using GCM platform - the app registers for a braodcast reciever and the broadcast receiver starts the service on getting the push notification...