# Android: keep Service running when app is killed

Tags: android, service, background, intentservice

I want to keep a `IntentService` running in background even when the app is killed. And by "killed" I mean *press home-button for a long time* -> *see all running apps* -> *swipe my app aside* -> *app killed* OR *press back-button for a long time* -> *app killed*

My code goes as follows. In my MainActivity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
this.startService(intent);
```

In my MyService:

```
public class MyService extends IntentService {

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    System.out.println("MyService started");
    run();
}

private void run() {
    while (true){
        System.out.println("MyService still running");
        doSomething();
        waitSomeTime();
    }
}

}
```

I see that the service is running when the app is *open*. It's still running when I *minimize the app* via home-button. It's still running when I *close the app* via back-button. But it will stop if I kill it as mentioned above. How do I solve this?

Comment: you can refer this. http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2013/05/how-to-make-android-service-unstoppable.html

Comment: i tried it (downloaded the example): yes, the service survives a kill via task manager, but it doesn't survive the "press back-button for a long time" kill. you have any idea?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Service Stops When App Is Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16651009/android-service-stops-when-app-is-closed)

Comment: Maybe my answer be useful for someone: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64113820/2877427

Comment: which is working actual these days in all of the answers ?

Answer (score 128):

*All the answers seem **correct** so I'll go ahead and give a **complete** answer here.*

Firstly, the easiest way to do what you are trying to do is launch a **Broadcast** in Android when the *app is killed* manually, and define a custom **`BroadcastReceiver`** to trigger a service restart following that.

Now lets jump into code.

---

**Create your Service in `YourService.java`**

Note the `onCreate()` method, where we are starting a **foreground service** differently for Build versions greater than *Android Oreo*. This because of the strict notification policies introduced recently where we have to define our own *notification channel* to display them correctly.

The `this.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);` in the `onDestroy()` method is the statement which asynchronously sends a broadcast with the action name **`"restartservice"`**. We'll be using this later as a trigger to restart our service.

Here we have defined a simple Timer task, which prints a counter value every **1 second** in the **`Log`** while incrementing itself every time it prints.

```
public class YourService extends Service {
public int counter=0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            startMyOwnForeground();
        else
            startForeground(1, new Notification());
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private void startMyOwnForeground()
    {
        String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "example.permanence";
        String channelName = "Background Service";
        NotificationChannel chan = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE);
        chan.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
        chan.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);
        
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        assert manager != null;
        manager.createNotificationChannel(chan);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
        Notification notification = notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true)
                .setContentTitle("App is running in background")
                .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN)
                .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
                .build();
        startForeground(2, notification);
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        startTimer();
        return START_STICKY;
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        stoptimertask();

        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
        broadcastIntent.setAction("restartservice");
        broadcastIntent.setClass(this, Restarter.class);
        this.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
    }



    private Timer timer;
    private TimerTask timerTask;
    public void startTimer() {
        timer = new Timer();
        timerTask = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                Log.i("Count", "=========  "+ (counter++));
            }
        };
        timer.schedule(timerTask, 1000, 1000); //
    }

    public void stoptimertask() {
        if (timer != null) {
            timer.cancel();
            timer = null;
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

---

**Create a Broadcast Receiver to respond to your custom defined broadcasts in `Restarter.java`**

The broadcast with the action name **`"restartservice"`** which you just defined in `YourService.java` is now supposed to trigger a method which will **restart your service**. This is done using **`BroadcastReceiver`** in Android.

We override the built-in `onRecieve()` method in **`BroadcastReceiver`** to add the statement which will restart the service. The `startService()` will **not work as intended** in and above Android Oreo 8.1, as *strict background policies* will soon terminate the service after restart once the app is killed. Therefore we use the `startForegroundService()` for higher versions and show a continuous notification to keep the service running.

```
public class Restarter extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("Broadcast Listened", "Service tried to stop");
        Toast.makeText(context, "Service restarted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            context.startForegroundService(new Intent(context, YourService.class));
        } else {
            context.startService(new Intent(context, YourService.class));
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Define your `MainActivity.java` to call the service on app start.**

Here we define a separate `isMyServiceRunning()` method to check the current status of the background service. If the service is *not* running, we start it by using `startService()`.

Since the app is already running in foreground, we need not launch the service as a **foreground service** to prevent itself from being terminated.

Note that in `onDestroy()` we are dedicatedly calling `stopService()`, so that our ***overridden method*** gets invoked. If this was not done, then the service would have ended *automatically* after app is killed without invoking our modified `onDestroy()` method in **`YourService.java`**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Intent mServiceIntent;
    private YourService mYourService;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mYourService = new YourService();
        mServiceIntent = new Intent(this, mYourService.getClass());
        if (!isMyServiceRunning(mYourService.getClass())) {
            startService(mServiceIntent);
        }
    }

    private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                Log.i ("Service status", "Running");
                return true;
            }
        }
        Log.i ("Service status", "Not running");
        return false;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        //stopService(mServiceIntent);
        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
        broadcastIntent.setAction("restartservice");
        broadcastIntent.setClass(this, Restarter.class);
        this.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

---

**Finally register them in your `AndroidManifest.xml`**

All of the above three classes need to be separately registered in **`AndroidManifest.xml`**.

Note that we define an `intent-filter` with the *action name* as `"restartservice"` where the **`Restarter.java`** is registered as a `receiver`.
This ensures that our custom **`BroadcastReciever`** is called whenever the system encounters a broadcast with the given *action name*.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <receiver
        android:name="Restarter"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="restartservice" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity android:name="MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name="YourService"
        android:enabled="true" >
    </service>
</application>
```

This should now restart your service again if the app was killed from the task-manager. This service will keep on running in background as long as the user doesn't **`Force Stop`** the app from **Application Settings**.

**UPDATE:** Kudos to [Dr.jacky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/421467/dr-jacky) for pointing it out. The above mentioned way will only work if the `onDestroy()` of the service is called, which might **not** be the case certain times, which I was unaware of. Thanks.

Comment: still this is not working in background when app is killed or background in oreo. it's working only when app is in foreground. .. please help to slove this.

Comment: Can you tell me your target sdk and minimum sdk of the project?

Comment: i put  minSdkVersion 15 and targetSdkVersion 26

Comment: Are you testing it on MIUI? If yes, I am sorry to say but they have a strict background tasks policy where they unconditionally kill all apps that are not whitelisted by them.

Comment: I just tried this, it works perfectly as explained on android N well this is not working on android kitkat 4.4

Comment: The Service's `onDestroy` might be not called: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7237522/421467

Comment: Thanks! I updated my answer to make sure that possibility is known. I learned something new today.

Comment: When we have already returned START_STICKY from onStartCommand() it means that the OS will restart the service if it is killed. Then why do we need a broadcast which starts a service in onDestroy() of the service? Isn't restarting already being taken care by the OS?

Comment: its not work, mine does not call onDestroy(), so how do we run service in the background indefinitely..

Comment: I'm trying this on my Oppo A3S. I used to have a foreground notification but the worker manager starts to slow down and eventually stops running after 8 hours or so. So with this, I see that a service is created within which foreground notification is created, which keeps the app running as a process and consumes considerable chunk of RAM. Will update after a day or so. PS- I am getting Ignore_battery_optimization permission and I am allowing auto startup and despite these, the worker used to stop.

Comment: In the "YourService" class, you use "greater-than" : Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.O. In the "Restarter" class, you use "greater-or-equal-to" (>=) for the same check. Is this correct or should one of them be changed?

Comment: @W3Coder greater-or-equal-to (>=) for both of them.

Comment: you can put the Intent restartservice on setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler

Comment: Do not forget about the android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE permission set up in the Android Manifest

Answer (score 55):

If your Service is started by your app then actually your service is running on main process. so when app is killed service will also be stopped. So what you can do is, send broadcast from `onTaskRemoved` method of your service as follows:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.ServiceStopped");
 sendBroadcast(intent);
```

and have an broadcast receiver which will again start a service. I have tried it. service restarts from all type of kills.

Comment: this is the right answer. I have written a simple example in a [blog entry](http://fabcirablog.weebly.com/blog/creating-a-never-ending-background-service-in-android)

Comment: plz tell me whats I am write in intent mean "com.android.ServiceStopped" what it mean which intent i called in sendBroadcast method is create a new intent to stop the service

Comment: @AhmadJoyia can you plz clarify ur question. I m not sure where exactly u r having issue.

Comment: @BhendiGawaar I do same thing as you said. But it is not working on customised OS phone like vivo, OPO, MIUI etc.

Comment: @RohanShinde Is it working on emulator? can you share what you have tried either as a separate question or on code sharing platforms?

Comment: Sometimes when the android specifies that it needs to kill a few process to free up more ram it doesn't even call `onTaskRemoved` form service. It just kills it.

Comment: I have using Lenovo TB3-730X. onTaskRemoved is not being called when app is killed by the user and i have tried with onDestroy too. It is also not working.kindly suggest me with any solution

Answer (score 20):

In your service, add the following code.

```
@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent){
    Intent restartServiceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), this.getClass());
    restartServiceIntent.setPackage(getPackageName());

    PendingIntent restartServicePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 1, restartServiceIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    AlarmManager alarmService = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmService.set(
    AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
    SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000,
    restartServicePendingIntent);

    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
 }
```

Comment: To get rid of the "Missing PendingIntent mutability flag" warning, replace `PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT` with `PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE`.

Answer (score 7):

inside onstart command put `START_STICKY`... This service won't kill unless it is doing too much task and kernel wants to kill it for it...

```
@Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            Log.i("LocalService", "Received start id " + startId + ": " + intent);
            // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly
            // stopped, so return sticky.
            return START_STICKY;
        }
```

Comment: works for the kill via task manager, but the service does not survive a "press back-button for a long time" kill :/

Comment: start sticky will run the service again after the app shuts down , so in a sense it will restart the service.

Comment: At some point if the user kills the app maybe we should respect the user and let the service die.

Answer (score 6):

The reason for this is that you are trying to use an IntentService. Here is the line from the [API Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

> The IntentService does the following:
>
> Stops the service after all start requests have been handled, so you
>   never have to call stopSelf().

Thus if you want your service to run indefinitely i suggest you extend the Service class instead. However this does not guarantee your service will run indefinitely. Your service will still have a chance of being killed by the kernel in a state of low memory if it is low priority.So you have two options:
1)Keep it running in the foreground by calling the `startForeground()`  method.
2)Restart the service if it gets killed. 
 Here is a part of the example from the docs where they talk about restarting the service after it is killed

```
 public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
      Toast.makeText(this, "service starting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

      // For each start request, send a message to start a job and deliver the 
      // start ID so we know which request we're stopping when we finish the job 
      Message msg = mServiceHandler.obtainMessage();
      msg.arg1 = startId;
      mServiceHandler.sendMessage(msg);

      // If we get killed, after returning from here, restart 
      return START_STICKY;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

use onTaskRemoved in your service class

```
 @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        Intent restartServiceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), this.getClass());

        PendingIntent restartServicePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
                getApplicationContext(), 1, restartServiceIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        AlarmManager alarmService = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmService.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, elapsedRealtime() + 500,
                restartServicePendingIntent);
        Log.d("taskremoved", "task removed ");
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    }
```

Comment: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent

Answer (score 1):

You can use `android:stopWithTask="false"`in manifest as bellow, This means even if user kills app by removing it from tasklist, your service won't stop.

```
 <service android:name=".service.StickyService"
                  android:stopWithTask="false"/>
```

Comment: It's false by default!!

Answer (score 0):

You try below code:

```
public class HeartbeartService extends Service {

private static final int SERVICE_NOTIFICATION_ID = 54321;
private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "Notification service";
private final LocalBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

Handler handler = new Handler();
private Runnable runnableCode = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, HeartbeatEventService.class);
        context.startService(myIntent);
        HeadlessJsTaskService.acquireWakeLockNow(context);
        handler.postDelayed(this, 2000);
        
    }
};

public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    public HeartbeartService getService() {
        return HeartbeartService.this;
    }
}

private void createNotificationChannel() {
    // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
    // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN;
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, "Notification service", importance);
        channel.setDescription("CHANEL DESCRIPTION");
        NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
}





@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
   
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    this.handler.removeCallbacks(this.runnableCode);
   
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    this.handler.post(this.runnableCode);
     createNotificationChannel();
     Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
     PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent,
             PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
     Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
             .setContentTitle("Notification service")
             .setContentText("Running...")
             .setBadgeIconType(0)
             .setAutoCancel(false)
             .setOngoing(true)
             .build();

    startForeground(1, notification);
  
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

}

Comment: please add explanation.

Comment: what do you need to be explained? I hope might help you. Ajay Chauhan

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i am triggering my alarms when the app is in background or even killed using foreground services:

```
  // Aware user about the foreground service
   private fun setForeGroundNotification() {
    val intent = Intent(this, AlarmForegroundService::class.java)
 
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        startForegroundService(intent)
    } else {
        startService(intent)
    }
}


 

public class AlarmForegroundService extends Service {
@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    final String CHANNELID = "Foreground Service ID";
    NotificationChannel channel;
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        channel = new NotificationChannel(
                CHANNELID,
                CHANNELID,
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW
        );

        getSystemService(NotificationManager.class).createNotificationChannel(channel);
        Notification.Builder notification = new Notification.Builder(this, CHANNELID)
                .setContentTitle("App is running in background to check alarm")
                .setContentText("Checking Alarm..")
                .setAutoCancel(false)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.logo);
        startForeground(1, notification.build());
    }
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    int hours = intent.getIntExtra("hours", 0);
    int minutes = intent.getIntExtra("minutes", 0);

    //Firing alarm at selected wake up time
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hours);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutes);

    //To prevent alarm trigger for past time.
    if (calendar.before(Calendar.getInstance())) {
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }

    Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            this,
            0,
            intent1,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
    );

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24), pendingIntent);
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

}

```
class AlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
    val intent = Intent(context, AlarmIntentService::class.java)
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        context!!.startForegroundService(intent)
    } else {
        context!!.startService(intent)
    }
}
```

}

```
public class AlarmIntentService extends Service {
@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    NotificationChannel channel = null;
    int notificationId = 123;
    long[] vibPattern = {1000, 1000, 1000, 1000};

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        channel = new NotificationChannel("channel2",
                "Sleep Alarm",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
    }

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        channel.setVibrationPattern(vibPattern);
    }

    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }

    //Creating the notification object
    NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "channel2");
    notification.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_bell);
    notification.setContentTitle("Wake up Alarm!!");
    notification.setContentText("It's time to get up");
    notification.setAutoCancel(true);
    notification.setSound(null);
    //notification.build().flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    //Action button handling
    Intent onDismiss = new Intent(this, DismissReceiver.class);
    onDismiss.putExtra("NOTIFICATION_ID", notificationId);
    Intent onSnooze = new Intent(this, SnoozeReceiver.class);


    SharedPreferences sh = getSharedPreferences("MySharedPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int snooze = sh.getInt("snooze", 0);

    PendingIntent dismissPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, onDismiss, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
    if (snooze == 0) {
        notification.setContentIntent(dismissPendingIntent);
        notification.addAction(R.drawable.ic_cross, "Dismiss", dismissPendingIntent);
    } else {
        PendingIntent snoozePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, onSnooze, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
        notification.setContentIntent(dismissPendingIntent);
        notification.setContentIntent(snoozePendingIntent);
        notification.addAction(R.drawable.ic_cross, "Dismiss", dismissPendingIntent);
        notification.addAction(R.drawable.ic_cross, "Snooze", snoozePendingIntent);
    }

    //To trigger the chosen alarm ringtone
    Intent startIntent = new Intent(this, RingtonePlayingService.class);
    this.startService(startIntent);

    manager.notify(notificationId, notification.build());
    startForeground(notificationId, notification.build());
}
```

}