# Media Player killed by Android system

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, kill, foreground-service

In my app, I have **Activity A** ( home activity) --->> then **Activity B** --->> Then **foreground** service.

Application runs for an hour then in notification bar I get **"This app is consuming power > 40mhA**". Within another hour the app is killed.

Reference to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30525784/android-keep-service-running-when-app-is-kille), it's possible to keep the service running even after killing the app , but this is not the target.

My question: is it possible to keep the app running and overcome system killing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, if the OS has decided to kill your application due to power consumption - there is nothing you can do to keep it running.

The best thing you can do is check why it consumes that much battery and optimize it through your code.
I know that sometimes it seems like there is nothing you can do to optimize it, but trust me, there is.
Maybe you are using a service in a wrong way that abuses it?

If you will post your code here we can try help you fix it :)