# A service is not working in background when I kill my application on Nougat

Tags: android, background, android-8.0-oreo, android-7.0-nougat

I have working in background task when I kill my application keep on check background task.

I want when Kill my application keep Every checking data from API any new data is there it's show local push notification. This code is working *marshmallow* and below version but *Nougat* and Above version not working can you help me.

```
    public class MyService extends Service {

        public static final int notify = 60*10*1000;  //interval between two services(Here Service run every 5 Minute)
        private Handler mHandler = new Handler(); 

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
        }

        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
            return START_STICKY;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            if (mTimer != null) // Cancel if already existed
                mTimer.cancel();
            else
                mTimer = new Timer();   //recreate new
                mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimeDisplay(), 0, notify);   //Schedule task
            //mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyTask(), millisToNextHour(calendar), 60*60*1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);


        }

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        @Override
        public void processFinish(String output) {



                if (count20new > count20old) {

                    //  Toast.makeText(MyService.this, "Service is running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(getApplicationContext());
                    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
                    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);
                    String message = "To see the latest message.";

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class);
                   // PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                    PendingIntent contentIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


                    NotificationCompat.Builder b = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext());
                    Resources res = getApplicationContext().getResources();

                    b.setAutoCancel(true)
                            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_final)
                            .setColor(Color.parseColor("#83c3ed"))
                            .setTicker("Check Latest Notification")
                            .setContentTitle(res.getString(R.string.app_name))
                            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
                            .setContentText(message)
                            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                            .setContentIntent(contentIntent);
                    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    notificationManager.notify(1, b.build());

                }


        }



        public int getProfilesCount() {
            Log.e("my_state","On start command6");


           Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
            count20new = cursor.getCount();
            cursor.close();
            return count20new;
        }

        //class TimeDisplay for handling task
        class TimeDisplay extends TimerTask {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {


                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        boolean isConnected = ConnectivityReceiver.isConnected(MyService.this);
                        if (isConnected) {
                            Notificationdata();
                        }

                    }
                });
            }
        }

       public  void Notificationdata(){
            Log.e("my_state","On start command8");

        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to start service as [ForegroundService](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30525784/4079010)

Comment: i tried ForegroundService i got problem is it's keep showing push notification, i want every once should be show push notification

Comment: Yes, from Oreo you cannot run background services without push notification.

Comment: i want to run background task every 2 hours to check data if any new data is available to intimate push notification to user like this i want. Higher version not working

Comment: You should use AlarmManager to acheive this