# Understanding the Life cycle of Activity and Service

Tags: android, android-service, android-lifecycle, activity-lifecycle, android-memory

Suppose I have multiple activities say Screen A(Main Screen) & Screen B.

Screen A opens Screen B and then Screen B starts a service which sends updates to Screen B. Now when the user minimizes the app and the service is running and since Android OS is short of memory then it clears the App.

Now I have two question

1) Does the Android OS clear the memory of the whole app (Screen A & Screen B) or only my Screen B?

2) Will my service also be cleared or will it continue to run? If it is cleared then can a foreground service with a notification help me to overcome this?

Any help would be grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now when the user minimizes the app and the service is running and since Android OS is short of memory then it clears the App.

When Android is short on memory, it terminates a process.

> Does the Android OS clear the memory of the whole app (Screen A & Screen B) or only my Screen B?

By default, your app uses a single process. So, when Android terminates your process, everything of your app goes away.

> Will my service also be cleared or will it continue to run?

By default, your app uses a single process. So, when Android terminates your process, your service will also go away. Some developers elect to put their service in a separate process (via the `android:process` manifest attribute) to help the service stay around longer, but that makes your app a bit more difficult to build.

> If it is cleared then can a foreground service with a notification help me to overcome this?

A foreground service makes it far less likely that Android will terminate that service's process to free up system RAM. However, [you should only have a service running when it is actively delivering value to the user](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/27/role-services.html).

Comment: Thanks. As per your answer, the app will kill a process which includes all the activities & service. I have one more doubt. Suppose I have an activity and a Foreground service running(same process as the activity) with a notification. Then if the App kills the process then will the service also be terminated? And if yes then will making the service return STICKY help to recreate the service immediately?

Comment: Also, Having a Foreground service with or without notification reduces the chances of Android OS killing my app's process?

Comment: @Rahulrr2602: "Then if the App kills the process then will the service also be terminated?" -- if the service is in that process, then the service will be destroyed. "And if yes then will making the service return STICKY help to recreate the service immediately?" -- I would go with "soon" rather than "immediately". Android is supposed to fork a fresh process for you and restart your service if your service is sticky. "Having a Foreground service with or without notification reduces the chances of Android OS killing my app's process?" -- foreground services have a `Notification`.

Comment: Thanks. By "without notification, I actually meant normal service, not foreground service. Sorry, it was my mistake. You have cleared all my doubts except one. Will running a foreground service with a Notification or a Normal service which are performing some work reduce the chance of Android OS to clear the process of my app/service even if the activities are running.

Comment: @Rahulrr2602: I covered that in the answer. A foreground service makes it far less likely that Android will terminate that service's process to free up system RAM. Whether there are also activities in that process does not matter. Note, though, that some devices have their own task managers where users can terminate processes manually, even ones with foreground services. In general, the user can always get rid of your process when the user wants.

Comment: What about normal service will they also reduce the chances of an Android OS clearing the process?

Comment: @Rahulrr2602: On Android 8.0+, a background service can only run for a minute, so it has little impact on the lifetime of your process. On older devices, a background service will help keep your process alive, but not as much as does a foreground service.

Comment: You have mentioned that ***"On Android 8.0+, a background service can only run for a minute"***. Did you exactly mean that it cannot run for more than 1 minute even if the app/service process is in the recent list or visible to the user. Asking this question as want not able to find this limitation in the background execution limits documentation https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background

Comment: "it cannot run for more than 1 minute even if the app/service process is in the recent list or visible to the user" -- if the app has foreground UI (e.g., the user can see an activity), then the process is a foreground process. If the app does not have foreground UI, and the service is a background service, the process is a background process. A service can only run for 1 minute in a background process. The overview screen ("recent list") is *not* part of the foreground from a UI standpoint, so being in there does not make an app's process be a foreground process.

Comment: Thanks Once again for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

1. Android OS will clear the whole app if it needs memory for other application.
2. If activity is destroyed, services within will be also destroyed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But Suppose I have a Foreground service running with a notification returning NOT_STICKY will it also be destroyed? If yes then will starting the service from Application context help? Or will making the service return STICKY help? Will accept your answer in 7 mins as cannot accept now due to StackOverflow restrictions

Comment: Yeah, it will be. You have a very good explanation here about foreground service and app killing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30525784/android-keep-service-running-when-app-is-killed

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Even though your answer was before CommonsWare's answer I have accepted his answer as it has a better explanation and his reputation is more hence other users might tend to believe his answer more. Sorry but hope you understand.