# Run a service even after the application gets killed in recents on newer android versions

Tags: android, service, android-service

I want to track the location of a person in a foreground service. For legitimate and legal reasons, I want to track the user's location continuously, even after the application is swiped from recents screen

Please note that the solutions provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30525784/android-keep-service-running-when-app-is-killed) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30525784/android-keep-service-running-when-app-is-killed?noredirect=1&lq=1) won't work as `onDestroy()` `onTaskRemoved()` won't be called when user swipes the application from recents.

Also, using `Broadcast Receivers` won't be of any help, as they only work when the task is not cleared.

I've also tried using a `ViewModel` and calling `onCleared()`. Even that doesn't seem to work.

Is there any way of doing this.

I need to keep the service running in the foreground as that is the primary need for my app.

Answer (score 0):

you can use WorkManager for this
[here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager)

Comment: I would like to start this service immediately, as soon as it closes. using a `workmanager` won't start the service immediately right?. Is there any workaround to start the service immediately?

Comment: Also, I've just discovered that we cannot start a foreground service from the background