# android - Alarm stops firing after some time

Tags: android, xamarin.android, alarmmanager, android-permissions, android-alarms

I have an alarm that fires every hour and executes code in specific conditions
It works smoothly, but when I leave my app unopened (the alarm initialization is on app startup) it stops after some time, these are the logs:

```
8/2/2020 6:27 AM Initializing Alarm, next alarm will fire at 8/2/2020 3:27 AM
8/2/2020 6:27 AM Application starting.
8/2/2020 6:28 AM Application stopped.
8/2/2020 6:28 AM Reports alarm received.
8/2/2020 7:28 AM Reports alarm received.
8/2/2020 8:28 AM Reports alarm received.
8/2/2020 9:28 AM Reports alarm received.
8/2/2020 9:28 AM Reports alarm finished.
8/2/2020 10:28 AM Reports alarm received.
8/2/2020 10:28 AM Reports alarm finished.
8/2/2020 11:28 AM Reports alarm received.
8/2/2020 11:28 AM Reports alarm finished.
8/2/2020 12:30 PM Reports alarm received.
8/2/2020 12:30 PM Reports alarm finished.
8/2/2020 1:30 PM Reports alarm received.
8/2/2020 1:30 PM Reports alarm finished.
8/2/2020 2:30 PM Reports alarm received.
8/2/2020 2:30 PM Reports alarm finished.
8/3/2020 8:13 AM Initializing Alarm, next alarm will fire at 8/3/2020 5:13 AM
```

As you see between 2:30 PM to 8:13 AM the next day, no alarms were fired

This is the initialization:

```
alarmMgr.SetInexactRepeating(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, calendar.TimeInMillis, 1000 * 60 * 60, alarmIntent);
```

I have acquired the WAKE_LOCK permission.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

AlarmManager work perfectly when the App is running in Foreground or in Background.

But when the App is quit/force-stopped/killed , Alarm Manager is cancelled.

Alarm will go off again only the App is again launched by the user.

To keep alarm alive when app closed you might have to use [Foreground service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/foreground-services) .

Here is a [sample](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/400780/#Comment_400780) you could refer to .

Comment: I'm not so sure that's how AlarmManager works, because I see many apps which doesn't use any services and still get to run code periodically, For fact: when my app is killed - it still works for a few hours then stops

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30525784/android-keep-service-running-when-app-is-killed, maybe helpful.