# How to receive last location when app is in background (when app is killed)

Tags: android, location, alarmmanager, android-workmanager

I have a problem and I have not solved the problem up to the present. I have searched a lot of blogs, StackOverflow posts, youtube videos, and documents for solving the problem. Every 15 minutes, I want to receive the last location and send it to my server, when my app is killed or background.

I have tried to do this process with WorkManager, AlarmManager, and Broadcast Receiver, but it does not work with some devices like Huwai, Xiaomi.

How can I solve this problem? Do you have any idea?

Thank you very much to everyone that answered.

Comment: Have you checked this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30525784/android-keep-service-running-when-app-is-killed

Comment: yes, I have checked it, but the implementation does not work in android 8 or newer. https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background