# Service doesn't work when app is closed, although earlier did

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-service

Here is the current code for `NotificationService.class`:

```
package com.mypack.appname;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.WebView;

import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationManagerCompat;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class NotificationService extends Service {

Timer timer;
TimerTask timerTask;
String TAG = "Timers";
int Your_X_SECS = 5;


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand");
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    startTimer();

    return START_STICKY;
}


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");


}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy");
    stoptimertask();
    super.onDestroy();


}

//we are going to use a handler to be able to run in our TimerTask
final Handler handler = new Handler();
public android.content.Context ant;

public void startTimer() {
    //set a new Timer
    timer = new Timer();
    ant = this;

    //initialize the TimerTask's job
    timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {

            //use a handler to run a toast that shows the current timestamp
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    //TODO CALL NOTIFICATION FUNC

                    new GetUrlContentTask().execute("some url here");
                }
            });
        }
    };

    //schedule the timer, after the first 5000ms the TimerTask will run every 10000ms
    timer.schedule(timerTask, 5000, Your_X_SECS * 1000); //
    //timer.schedule(timerTask, 5000,1000); //
}

public void stoptimertask() {
    //stop the timer, if it's not already null
    if (timer != null) {
        timer.cancel();
        timer = null;
    }
}

private class GetUrlContentTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
            connection.setReadTimeout(5000);
            connection.connect();
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            String content = "", line;
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                content += line + "\n";
            }

            if(Objects.equals(content,"{\"nocomments\":true"))
                return content;

            JSONObject o = new JSONObject(content);
            String m_id = o.getString("id");
            JSONArray a = o.getJSONArray("comments");
            int le = a.length();

            SharedPreferences settings = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("prefnameaga", 0);
            int lele = settings.getInt(m_id, 0);

            if(lele != le)
            {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                editor.putInt(m_id, le);
                editor.apply();

                JSONObject la = a.getJSONObject(le-1);
                String data = la.getString("data");

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);

                NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), "IMACHANNE");
                builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground);
                builder.setContentTitle("New comment for the post");
                builder.setContentText(data);
                builder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
                builder.setAutoCancel(true);
                builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

                NotificationManagerCompat ntf = NotificationManagerCompat.from(getApplicationContext());
                ntf.notify(1, builder.build());
            }



  
            return content;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return "error";
        }
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // this is executed on the main thread after the process is over
        // update your UI here
        // displayMessage(result);

    }
}

}
```

Earlier, in `void Run()` there was code for showing "hello world" notification only. In `MainActivity` I wrote to start the service when `onStop()` is called. Notification has been arriving when the user switched to antoher app (not closing current), but when user closed the app, notificaion didn't come. I fixed that adding `android:stopWithTask="false"` to `service` in manifest.

Now I added some new features, and the code is as You see it above. For some reason, now I am facing that issue again: when the app is switched notification is showed absolutely correctly: http request is made succusesfully, all is good. But when the app is closed - nothing is happening.

What mistake did I do, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52258125/15220214) helped me to solve my problem (yet I still don’t know why it worked earlier) with some modification: in my notification service class I removed all from `onCreate` and in `onDestroy` I removed part for service restarting, because I need to service run only when the app is closed or killed.

Comment: There might be two reason 1. You were using a device which is lower than VERSION_CODES.O And, 2. Maybe, in new updates of android-studio lot of things were deprecated(not workable on every device).

Comment: @Istiak, unfortunately I test on the same device with Android 8.1, and seems my Android Studio haven’t been updated too