# Receive notifications after app is in Doze

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications, android-doze

**Given**

1. Target OS versions: 4.4 – 10;
2. App meant to be published in Google Play;
3. App idea is public transport tracking (notifying when the specific bus is about to arrive to specific bus stop).

**Problem**

I was working on implementing notifications that will be displayed after app is closed/killed, facing some issues [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66475185/15220214). But, then, when I found solution, all works fine. I thought it did.

I have been testing notifications again, and noticed, that, after app closing or killing, notifications are appeared **but** only during 1-2 minutes after closing/killing. Then noting is working (I also tested toast, etc.)

I started googling, and read about Doze (I am testing on Android 8.1). I went to settings and turned off battery optimization for my app. Now notifications are displayed and after 1-2 minutes, all is working.

**Question**

At the same time Telegram, Instagram and others apps that always display notifications, after 1 minute or 1 hour, are **battery optimized**.

How do they display notification in Doze?

---

I read about Firebase. I hope this is not the only one solution. And currently, I even didn’t understand how it can help, but even, if can, if it is the only solution it is very stupid.

Comment: Are you using high priority fcm notifications?

Comment: @Rajesh.k I do not use FCM currently. I am using solution I mentioned in post.

Comment: For your problem you can make your service as foreground service. example service code can be found here. https://github.com/android/location-samples/blob/master/LocationUpdatesForegroundService/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/location/sample/locationupdatesforegroundservice/LocationUpdatesService.java

Comment: @Rajesh.k thank You, I will try it, but it seems to be pretty similar to what I already have. Did You read the solution I mentioned in the current question, and origin, where I took it from (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30525784/android-keep-service-running-when-app-is-killed/52258125#52258125)?

Comment: The solution mentioned in that link is not official way to implement foreground service. it will cause problems like showing notification " the app is running in the background". so build proper notification object for startforeground method.

Comment: @Rajesh.k ok I’ll try, though I haven’t faced that problems, You write about.