# Scheduling Recurring Tasks in Xamarin Android and iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am using Xamarin to develop an Android/iOS application. The client has a requirement where, if the device gets within a distance of a predefined location, the app will send them a notification.

I imagined that I would need some kind of background task running that will check their location at regular intervals, sending them the notification if close enough. However, documentation like [Introduction to Backgrounding in iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/backgrounding/introduction-to-backgrounding-in-ios) and [Creating Android Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/) seems to talk about background tasks in the context of an already running or suspended app, unless I am misunderstanding. I need this task to be running even if the application is closed and not in use.

How can I create a task in my Android and iOS application that will check the device location periodically, and send a notification when near the predefined location?

Comment: Do you mean [Android: keep Service running when app is killed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30525784/android-keep-service-running-when-app-is-killed)

Comment: [Background fetch after app is force-quit](https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/666149)