# Cannot using BroadcastReceiver with LocalBroadcastManager

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter, intentservice, localbroadcastmanager

I have **1 activity** and **1 service**. The **service** will be started when the **activity** comes into background and will be stopped when the **activity** comes into foreground. When the service stops, I want to send an object from it to the **activity** by intent. Here is my code

> MyActivity.java

```java
private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_WITH_RLM)) {                
        //I will get the object received by service here 
        }
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_record_lesson_ins);

    localBroadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(ACTION_WITH_RLM);
    localBroadcastManager.registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (intent != null) {
        stopService(intent);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (intent != null) {
        startService(intent);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    localBroadcastManager.unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
}
```

> MyService.java

```
private RecordLessonModel recordLessonModel;

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    //I code sth for handle recordLessonModel object
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.ACTION_WITH_RLM);
    intent.putExtra(MyActivity.RECORD_MODEL_NAME, Parcels.wrap(recordLessonModel));
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

The problem here is my `broadcastReceiver` in `MyActivity` cannot receive intent from service when my **activity** comes to foreground. I don't know why.

Thanks.

Comment: is your `onReceive()` getting called?

Comment: Try to send broadcast from any other mothod, not `onDestroy`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7237522/1723695

Comment: @Wizard: no, my onReceive() has not been called yet

Comment: @g4s8: I only want to send broadcast when my service stop, so which methods I can use?
P/s: I tried to send broadcast from startCommand() method, but it still not works :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider unregistering your broadcastReceiver into `onDestory()` instead of `onStop()`

*because your brodcastReceiver is getting unregistered when activity goes background*.

For more look at [HERE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

Comment: Please provide some details along with your answer so it doesn't looks like a comment, Thanks.

Comment: provided explanation.