# onDestroy not called on Service when using stopWithTask="true"

Tags: android, android-service

I have a foreground `Service` which is used for audio recording (`AudioRecordingService`). Declared in `AndroidManifest` as such:

```
<service
     android:name=".recording.AudioRecordingService"
     android:stopWithTask="true" />
```

It extends `Service` and is started with `startService`

`public class AudioRecordingService extends Service`

Intents are received in `onStartCommand`.

In `onDestroy` I stop the audio recording and launch another foreground service which handles the audio upload.

`onDestroy` is not called in `AudioRecordingService` when the app is closed by swiping the app away (closing the task). It is only called when `stopSelf` is called on the service.

Comment: Service#onDestroy is not guaranteed to be called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it's not guaranteed that `onDestroy` will be called.
More information can be found in this post: [Is an android service guaranteed to call onDestroy()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7236782/is-an-android-service-guaranteed-to-call-ondestroy)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set your activity to be a task.

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack

see: "singleTask"

Comment: I am using a `Service`, not an `Activity`.
"singleTask" is the Activity's launchMode. It describes how the activity is started.

Comment: I understand, I  believe for stopwithtask to work that your activity needs to be a task.
https://developer.xamarin.com/api/field/Android.Resource+Attribute.StopWithTask/