# Notification from IntentService

Tags: android, android-service, intentservice

I developed an app which should remind me at a certain time. Therefore I implemented an IntentService which starts a notification. The problem is that the notification will be created while the app is in foreground or at least in background open. If I close the app using the task manager the notification is no longer running.

Am I using the wrong service? Or do I have to create something else?

**in the intentservice class:**

```
private static final String serviceName = "sebspr.de.deadlines.DeadLineService";

public DeadLineService() {
    super(serviceName);
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    Context ctx = getApplicationContext();
    Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, DeadLineService.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0, intent, 0);


    String title = getTitle(list.size());
    String text = getText(list);
    Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(ctx)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(text).setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_notfi)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .build();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // hide the notification after its selected
    noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    notificationManager.notify(0, noti);



}
```

**int the MainActivity:**

```
Intent msgIntent = new Intent(this, DeadLineService.class);
startService(msgIntent);
```

**UPDATE**

Considering my actual problem the solution is, to take a look at the AlarmManager. The IntentService is here the wrong way to go. I found a good tutorial here: [AlarmManger Example](http://javatechig.com/android/repeat-alarm-example-in-android)

Comment: And in your opinion if app closed via task manager it still should show notification or ..?

Comment: You kill the app in task manager, it'll delete the notification because you killed the app.  That's precisely what is supposed to happen.

Comment: Okay. But I want that the user still gets the notification. How can I handle this?

Answer (score 2):

You *shouldn't worry* about a user killing the app via the task manager. If that happens, you really shouldn't start back up automatically. It isn't a user-friendly way to do things.

What you *should* worry about is a **system restart** in which case you can register your app to be notified when the device turns on.

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4562804/2350083) answer for more details on starting your service when the phone turns on.

Also start your service [sticky](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY)

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) { 
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually u can try to keep your application alive after killed but it may annoy your users a bit... So, Look out...

[How to save Alarm after app killing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916859/how-to-save-alarm-after-app-killing)